# Play Framework - "Invalid value" when using helpers.select

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

When I try to submit a form in Play 2.4, I get the error "Invalid value". This is my code:
Form:

```
@helper.select(
    field = form("category"),
    options = categories.map {c =>
        c.name.toString -> c.name
    },
    '_default -> "Choose One"
)
```

Model that form is submitting to (has a one to one with category):

```
@OneToOne
@Constraints.Required
@Column
public Category category;
```

Category model:

```
@Entity
public class Category extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String name;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String description;

    public Category(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public static Finder<String, Category> find = new Finder<String,   Category>(Category.class);

    public static List<Category> getCategories() {
        return find.all();
    }
}
```

The form loads the id and name of the categories, it's just when I submit, that the error happens. I think it may be because Play is not getting the Category with the id when it searches the OneToOne relationship?

Comment: Please, post the complete stack trace and also the controller that is receiving the post request.

Comment: And, BTW, you are not sending `(id, name)` but instead `(name, name)`. Your `categories.map` must map to `c.id -> c.name` tuple if you want `(id, name)`.